# MVC @Foreach how to display only top 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How do I return only the top 5 in a view with a `@Foreach` in my index page. Everything I can find uses `@foreach (var item in Model.Take(3))`. But this does not work.

Here is the code I am working with:

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    dynamic model = new ExpandoObject();
    model.Employee = GetEmployeeInfo();
    return View(model);
}

private static List<Employee> GetEmployeeInfo()
{
    List<Employee> EmployeeInfo = new List<Employee>();
    string query = "SELECT ID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName Employee, PhoneExt FROM Employees WHERE NOT PhoneExt IS NULL ORDER BY FirstName ASC";
    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Conn"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query))
        {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            con.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (sdr.Read())
                {
                    EmployeeInfo.Add(new Employee
                    {
                        ID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["ID"]),
                        FirstName = sdr["Employee"].ToString(),
                        PhoneExt = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["PhoneExt"])
                    });
                }
            }

            con.Close();
            return EmployeeInfo;
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
@foreach (Employee EmployeeInfo in Model.Employee)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b> @Html.ActionLink(EmployeeInfo.FirstName, "Details", "Employees", new { id = EmployeeInfo.ID }, null)</b>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top">@EmployeeInfo.PhoneExt</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Comment: What do *you* mean with "doesn't work"? What does happen? Any errors? Why do you use Take(3) what you want a top-5?

Comment: Their model is dynamic. Hence they are unable to call `Take` on the employee list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Take(5) with dynamic model probably will give you Runtime Binder Exception. 
Ideally, modify your original query to only return 5 rows.
Otherwise you should map your results with list of Employee class, like below:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    List<Employee> model = GetEmployeeInfo();
    return View(model);
}
```

and then model this in your view and then you can use Take(5)

```
@model List<Employee>
@foreach (Employee EmployeeInfo in Model.Take(5))
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            <b> @Html.ActionLink(EmployeeInfo.FirstName, "Details", "Employees", new { id = EmployeeInfo.ID }, null)</b>
        </td>
        <td style="vertical-align:top">@EmployeeInfo.PhoneExt</td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

How about changing your query to take 5:

```cs
 string query = "SELECT TOP(5) ID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName Employee, PhoneExt FROM Employees WHERE NOT PhoneExt IS NULL ORDER BY FirstName ASC";
```

Comment: My end goal is to put a search box to filter the results in the view so I need all the results from the SQL query.

Comment: May be dynamic object is not the best choice in that case.